# What is the Sequelize equivalent of Mongoose's pre('save')?

Tags: postgresql, mongoose, sequelize.js, bcrypt

I'd like to hash a user password using bcrypt prior to storing it in a postgres database. Using MongoDB and Mongoose, I would have utilized pre('save') to hash the password before saving it. Is anyone familiar with the Sequelize equivalent? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using sequelize hooks:

`beforeSave(instance, options, fn)`